# How to access exception in Camel errorHandler?

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

## Use Case

I'd like to log unhandled exceptions for a particular route in Camel in a reusable manner. Specifically, I'd like to extract enough information from the exception and write it to the database, which is then read by some monitoring software. Through the use of a dead letter queue, I was able to have all unhandled exceptions for a specific route routed there. Unfortunately, the exception in the exchange is always `null` when it is passed to the logger.

### Sample Code

The code below forces an exception to be thrown, which is then routed to the error handler. I was expecting `exchange.getException()` to return the exception that was thrown, but in this case it is `null`.

#### Java Code

```
public class JobRunner {

    public void run(Exchange exchange) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Hello, World!");
    }

    public void processException(Exchange exchange) {
        Exception e = exchange.getException();
        // e is null
    }

}
```

#### Camel Config

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <errorHandler id="jobErrorHandler"
        type="DeadLetterChannel"
        deadLetterUri="seda:errorHandler" />

    <route id="routeErrorHandler">
        <from uri="seda:errorHandler" />
        <bean ref="jobRunner" method="processException" />
    </route>

    <route id="scheduled_job" errorHandlerRef="jobErrorHandler">
        <from uri="quartz2://test/job?cron=0+*/5+*+*+*+?" />
        <bean ref="jobRunner" method="run" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

## Questions

- How can exceptions be routed to an error handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found out that the original exception is stored as a property in the Exchange.

```
Exception e = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
```